# I am unable to clone a bitbucket repository that I have write access level

Tags: python, git, ssh, pycharm, bitbucket

I have multiple ssh on my computer (not really sure how to say this), and believe this could be the reason I cannot pull, push, or clone using pycharm.

when I type this code into terminal:

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org:#####/#######.git
```

I get the error:

```
Cloning into '######'...

ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org:##### port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My coworkers at this startup have access and are able to clone and push into it. I believe that the reason could be that I use ssh for another program on my computer. But I'm not sure how that could affect it. I got this from google searches so I could also be mistaken. Anyone else run into this situation?

Comment: Locate your key on the server - typically /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and copy its content to Account ->  Bucket Settings -> SSH Keys -> Add Key.  To locate the key run   find / -name id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try in another way, it would be easier to clone a repository

try this:

```
git clone https://example@bitbucket...
```

in this way u could clone the repository without ssh keys

what's more, you could check the website below:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/copy-your-git-repository-and-add-files-746520876.html